# Integrate lognormal pdf multiplied by an exponential to find the mean and variance of transmission through a lognormally varying medium

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, definite-integrals

Seeking to find the mean and standard deviation of two-way transmission of light through a slab whose optical depth is a lognormal random variable.
The expression for the mean is
$$\overline T  = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\exp \left( { - 2x} \right)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } \sigma x}}} \exp \left[ { - \frac{{{{\left( {\ln x - \mu } \right)}^2}}}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}} \right]dx$$
where $T = \exp ( - 2x)$ is the two-way transmission, $x$ is the one-way optical depth, $\mu  = \overline {\ln x} $, and ${\sigma ^2} = {\mathop{\rm var}} \left( {\ln x} \right)$.  An algebraic solution is desired, but my attempts to solve have been in vain.
An alternative formulation by using $y = \ln x$ is
$$\overline T  = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{\exp \left( { - 2{e^y}} \right)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } \sigma }}} \exp \left[ { - \frac{{{{\left( {y - \mu } \right)}^2}}}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}} \right]dy$$
The expressions for the second moment of $T$ are the same, except in the integral $ - 2x$ becomes $ - 4x$, and $ - 2{e^y}$ becomes $ - 4{e^y}$.